# inline code as a "word" in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, knitr

Is it possible to make sublime text consider all code within backticks to be a single word?  I am including inline code in a markdown document, and it keeps breaking when I wrap a paragraph and inserts a newline in the midst of a code chunk.  For example

`` This is the text I am writing and `r this_is_some_code` ``

If the line is long, and a newline falls between `` `r ``  and the final backtick, then the code doesn't work correctly.  Is it possible to make that whole region be considered a single word?  then it would not wrap at the ruler at all.